# If I use cannons, will they be less effective against shields?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Other games say that lasers are more effective against shields and cannons against hull. Is it the same in Elite:Dangerous?

Answer (score 9):

**Yes.** Thermic weapons are the best against shields, kinetic and explosive weapons are the best against the hull. You can't just equip 4 cannons or 4 missile racks and expect things to go your way.

Comment: you can still do damage to shields with kinetic weapons, just not as much. It's very possible to run full kinetic and still be deadly in battle (see anacondas with nothing but turreted multi cannons)

Comment: @Rapitor That's very true, kinetic does some damage to shields. Explosives, on the other hand, do not. (as of 1.1)

Comment: In my experience with a Vulture with twin pulse lasers, lasers also do just fine against the hull. Kinetics just do better.

Comment: The performance of kinetic weapons against shields was nerfed back in beta 3.

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Weapons) Energy weapons are effective at stripping shields, but less effective at destroying hull armor.